# Split single video input files into 30 second blocks

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to split several video files (.mov) into 30 second blocks.

I do not need to specify where the 30 seconds start or finish.

**EXAMPLE**- A single 45 second video (VID1.mov) will be split into VID1_part1.mov (30 seconds), VID1_part2.mov (15 seconds). Ideally, I can remove audio too.

I made an attempt, using bash (osx), but was unsuccessful. It did not split the video into multiple parts- instead it just seemed to modify the original file (and made it into a length of 1-2 seconds):

```
find . -name '*.mov' -exec ffmpeg -t 30 -i \{\} -c copy \{\} \;
```

Comment: Your video is inside an MOV container. If you want to split it into files, I believe you need to add the bitsream headers ( refer to the video specs. ) as well. I think this is why you are able to playback only the first chunk of the original clip. Try clipping/playing back your video into lesser (maybe 4-5) pieces and you might will understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FFmpeg's segment muxer for this.

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -segment_time 30 -f segment input%d.mov
```

Depending on where the video keyframes are, each segment won't start at mod 30 secs. You'll have to omit `-c copy` for that.

Also, FFmpeg does not do in-place editing. Your bash script seems to present the input name for output as well. That won't work.

Comment: You've written `input`. For my example, I want to simple do all .mov files in the directory (so I replaced `input` with `*.mov`). However, when I run that, it says "video 1.mov already exists- overwrite?". Shouldn't it just create new segments out of it?

Comment: you can't use the wildcard after the `-i` of ffmpeg - it will simply see `-i file1 file2 file3 ...` and assume that file2 is an output file, you have to create a loop in the shell around it

Comment: Even when I specify the file, that simply copies the entire video, full length, and renames it input%d.mov...